# How to make a triangle with background from the main content

Tags: html, css

Currently I have my boxes looking like this:

[image]

How can I make the background image in any of the boxes affect in the triangles already so it looks like this?
[image]

A the moment my code looks like this and I am struggling to achieve that.

```css
.first,
.second,
.third {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first {
  background: red;
}

.first:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top-color: red;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.second {
 background-image: url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/04/09/6359580807140768861266757027_Never-Study-Hard-The-Art-of-Studying-Smart.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-repear: no-repeat;
}
.inner_second{
  background: blue;
  opacity; 0.8;
}

.second:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.third {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="inner_first">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <div class="inner_second">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="third">
  <div class="inner_third">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this using 2 pseudo element before an after.. Little hack

```css
.first,
.second,
.third {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first {
  background: red;
}

.first:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top-color: red;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.second {
 background-image: url('http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/04/09/6359580807140768861266757027_Never-Study-Hard-The-Art-of-Studying-Smart.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.inner_second{
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.second::before {
  top: calc(100% - (30px * 2));
  left: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-left-width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.second::after {
  top: calc(100% - (30px * 2));
  right: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.third {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="inner_first">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <div class="inner_second">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="third">
  <div class="inner_third">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to add an overflow in the box where I have the background-image to accomplish the same it is on the desired pictured but am struggling to make it work because of the apparent padding in the div with the class second. Here my pen.https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/w07ycfnc/

Comment: @WosleyAlarico what is the problem ?